# Binding with ANGULAR

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on project with Angular 12 and I have an HTML response I want to display. I want to bind innerHtml of div to variable value
I use this syntax {{value}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [innerHTML] property binding to your element , like this :

```
<div [innerHTML]="response"></div>
```